# Python: search csv file for specific string and store row number for later use

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that is output from a ventilatory gas analysis program that I am trying to (eventually) get into a pd data frame.  The problem is the file has a bunch of 'summary data' at the top before it gets to the raw data.  I can't program in a specific row as the number of rows used for the summary data can vary from file to file.  There is a constant at the top of the raw data that could be searched for and if I could identify the row that could be used to base the extraction on.

The screen shot below shows the file open in excel - the part I want to be able to search for is the TIME in A27.

[image]

Current code I've been messing around with to try and find the row and print it:

```
import csv

with open('parvo_sb.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in datareader:
        if row[0] == 'TIME ': # the file oddly saves with a space after TIME
            print(row)
```

But throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/Parvo/import.py", line 6, in <module>
    if row[0] == 'TIME ':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What I don't get about the error is that if I, for example, print(row[0]) i get that same error, but if I print(row[:1]), I can print the 'TIME' and not get the error.

Once I have the row number I have the code to extract everything to a pd df just stuck on this little hurdle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Invalid index access.
2. Storing the matched row number as per title.

For the first problem solutions have already been provided.
Nevertheless, here is one more using EAFP.
Regarding the second problem, you can make use of enumerate and a tracking variable:

```
import csv

first_time_line = None

with open('parvo_sb.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line, row in enumerate(datareader):
        try:
            first_column = row[0]
        except IndexError:
            continue
        else:
            # the file oddly saves with a space after TIME
            if first_column.strip() == 'TIME': 
                print(row)
                if first_time_line is None:
                    first_time_line = line
```

Comment: I've never used the try/except commands before. Am I correct in my understanding that the script tries to read the first column in a row but if it throws an error (like when the row is empty) it move into the except commands (which contains continue so it skips the row)? But if it can read the first column it skips except and performs the code under else?

Comment: Exactly. If there is no first column (`row[0]`), it's access will raise an `IndexError`, which is handled within the `except` block. Otherwise, if there was no exception at all, the `else` block is run.
In the current case you could also remove the `else:` and outdent the respective block, which should have the same effect.

Comment: That makes sense.  So the code you posted works for that file on my Uni PC and my MacBook flawlessly, however when I try to read a file from another analyser it works on my Uni PC but I get the following error on my MacBook (comment below) line 16 where the error occurs corresponds to `for line, row in enumerate(datareader):` in your code above

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Braden/Dropbox/CPET_python/import_cortex.py", line 16, in <module>
    for line, row in enumerate(data):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 1783: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are having empty lines, using `row[0]` is dangerous and may end with an error, as you already know about.

Moreover, to avoid having to match `'TIME '` instead of `'TIME'`, you could either use `strip()` or `startswith()` string methods.

You should try:

```
if len(row) > 1:
    first_col = row[0].strip()
    if first_col == 'TIME':
        # your logic goes here
```

or, if you don't want to define a new variable :

```
if len(row) > 1:
    if row[0].startswith('TIME'):
        # your logic goes here
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution could be is that you can store the file into memory for fast processing with this code rather than doing the I/O operations again and again.

```js
import csv

csvfile = open('my.csv','rb')
csvFileArray = []
for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ','): // Check your delimiter as well
  csvFileArray.append(row) // Storing the data into memory
print(csvFileArray[0][0]) //get the 'Time' over here, easily iterable 2Darray
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on which I/O operations the OP's code is repeating?